# i have been trying to install new man on my mac but i'm not able to generate html reports in my mac i'm getting the below error

Tags: newman

npm install -g newman
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.

i have been  trying to install new man on my mac but i'm not able to generate html reports in my mac i'm getting the above error

Comment: Did you try to install it by executing `brew install newman`?

Comment: npm install -g newman-reporter-html         i used this command to install html reports in node eventhough im not able to workout it .im getting same error after i install brew

Comment: I don't think it's actionable from your side, so you can ignore it. It's just a warning btw, not an error